# Happens va Happened

Tags: meaning

Do these two phrases mean the same thing "What happened in the movie?" and "what happens on the movie"

Thanks in advance

Comment: **happens on the movie** does not exist in English. Therefore, the two does not mean the same.

Comment: When you wrote "what happens on the movie", did you mean to write "what happens in the movie" (with "in" instead of "on")?

Comment: It's usual to refer to incidents in a fictional book or film in the present tense, so most people would say 'What happens _in_ the movie?'

Answer (score 1):

If you're discussing the movie in general, it's normal to use the present tense to refer to the actions.

However, you may sometimes need to refer to specific parts of the movie in relation to others, and then you'd use the past tense to refer to earlier parts, e.g. "What happened in the movie before they kissed?"

Also, if you're asking the question while you're watching the movie, you use the past tense. For instance, "What happened in the movie while I went out to the restroom?"

Answer (score 0):

I've heard both "What happens in the movie?" and "What happened in the movie?", but in different contexts.

The first implies that someone is interested in seeing a move that they may have heard of. For example, "I've heard that there's a new Star Wars movie out. What happens in the movie?"

The second implies (to me at least) a shared experience of watching the movie together. My friend went out to get popcorn and misses part of the action. When he returns, he asks me "What happened (in the movie)?" or more simply, "What did I miss?".

I know that these aren't great answers, but the question is quite subtle.